# React js call setInterval with conditon and clear setInterval

Tags: reactjs

how can i call two permanent services, i want to call the first service every 5 seconds, after once results of the first service return a value different from 0, I want to call a second service with the value returned by the first service every 5 seconds also, until I receive a value, How can I do this with react setInterval doesn't work.

```
  const {info,data} = useSelector((state) => ({
info : state.reducerData.info,
data : state.reducerData.data,


})
   useEffect(() =>{
        var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
             dispatch(getData(id));
         },(5000))

         if(data?.sum != 0){
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId)
        }
     },[id]) 

    useEffect(() =>{
        var interval = setInterval(() => {
            if(data?.sum !=0){
                dispatch(getInfoData())
            }
        },(5000))
        if( info == sum){
            clearInterval(interval)
        } 
    },[data])
```

Comment: Where is `data.sum` and `info` being written? There is no logic in there that assigns the results to the variables used in your `if` block

Comment: i use redux data is the result of getData and info is the result of getInfoData

Comment: `setInterval` doesn't necessarily work as you expect with hooks as it does in old React. Dan Abramov wrote an article on this: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/ Idk if this is what you're running into but it's likely involved